# Appending dataframes from json files in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to iterate through json files in a folder and append them all into one pandas dataframe.

If I say

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import os


directory_in_str = 'building_data'
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

df_all = pd.DataFrame()
with open("building_data/rooms.json") as file:
  data = json.load(file)
df = json_normalize(data['rooms'])
df_y.append(df, ignore_index=True)
```

I get a dataframe with the data from the one file. If I turn this thinking into a for loop, I have tried

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import os

directory_in_str = 'building_data'
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

df_all = pd.DataFrame()
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(directory_in_str+'/'+filename) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    df = json_normalize(data['rooms'])
    df_all.append(df, ignore_index=True)

print(df_all)
```

This returns an empty dataframe. Does anyone know why this is happening? If I print `df` before appending it, it prints the correct values, so I am not sure why it is not appending.

Thank you!

Comment: Was facing the same issue. This is because append does not work inplace. `df_all = df_all.append(df, ignore_index=True)` will work. However, it's worth noting that this is not a time-efficient solution for large data frames: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489576/why-does-concatenation-of-dataframes-get-exponentially-slower/36489724#36489724

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of append next DataFrame I would try to join them like that:

```
if df_all.empty:
    df_all = df
else:
    df_all = df_all.join(df)
```

When joining DataFrames, you can specify on what they should be joined - on index or on specific (key) column, as well as how (default option is similar to appending - 'left').

Here's docs about [pandas.DataFrame.join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html).

Answer (score 1):

In these instances I load everything from json into a list by appending each file's returned dict onto that list. Then I pass the list to `pandas.DataFrame.from_records` ([docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html))

In this case the source would become something like...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import os

directory_in_str = 'building_data'
directory = os.fsencode(directory_in_str)

json_data = []
for file in os.listdir(directory):
    with open(directory_in_str+'/'+filename) as file:
        data = json.load(file)
    json_data.append( json_normalize(data['rooms']) )

df_all = pandas.DataFrame.from_records( json_data )

print(df_all)
```